# How do I parse data in Oracle?

Tags: oracle, function, parsing

I have two tables that are linked by a common column 'ID'. Table1 has text with fill in the blanks (%1,%2,... %10) and Table2 has values for those blanks separated by a / delimiter.

Expected result is to fill in the blanks and display complete sentence as a select statement and/or by creating a function.

Any help is much appreciated!!!

Note:
Oracle version: 11g. Table1 can have up to 10 values to be filled (%10)

Table1:

| ID | TEXT |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | It is %1 today with a %2 sky. |
| 2 | It is %1 today with %2 and chances of %3. |
| 3 | I just %1 have a %2 that %3 understand. We %4 need %5 to %6 on. |

Table2:

| CODE | ID | VALUES |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | 1 | sunny/bright blue |
| A2 | 2 | rainy/severe thunder storms/flooding |
| A3 | 3 | might/problem/you'll/all/somebody/lean |
| A4 | 1 | rainy/dark |

Expected Output:

| CODE | OUTPUT TEXT |
| --- | --- |
| A1 | It is sunny today with a bright blue sky. |
| A2 | It is rainy today with severe thunder storms and chances of flooding. |
| A3 | I just might have a problem that you'll understand. We all need somebody to lean on. |
| A4 | It is rainy today with a dark sky. |

I tried to search for a solution but no luck or maybe I am not searching right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a variable number of terms, you can do it without regular expressions using a recursive query:

```sql
WITH replacements (id, text, variables, idx) AS (
  SELECT t1.id,
         t1.text,
         t2.vals,
         LENGTH(t2.vals) - LENGTH(REPLACE(t2.vals, '/')) + 1
  FROM   table1 t1
         INNER JOIN table2 t2
         ON (t1.id = t2.id)
UNION ALL
  SELECT id,
         REPLACE(
           text,
           '%'||idx,
           SUBSTR(variables, INSTR(variables, '/', -1) + 1)
         ),
         SUBSTR(variables, 1, INSTR(variables, '/', -1) - 1),
         idx - 1
  FROM   replacements
  WHERE  idx > 0
)
SELECT id, text
FROM   replacements
WHERE  idx = 0;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table1 (ID, TEXT) AS
SELECT 1, 'It is %1 today with a %2 sky.' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'It is %1 today with %2 and chances of %3.' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'I just %1 have a %2 that %3 understand. We %4 need %5 to %6 on.' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, '%1%2%3%4%5%6%7%8%9%10' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE Table2 (ID, VALS) AS
SELECT 1, 'sunny/bright blue' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'rainy/severe thunder storms/flooding' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'might/problem/you''ll/all/somebody/lean' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'rainy/gloomy' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'A/B/C/D/E/F/G/H/I/J' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| ID | TEXT |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | It is sunny today with a bright blue sky. |
| 1 | It is rainy today with a gloomy sky. |
| 2 | It is rainy today with severe thunder storms and chances of flooding. |
| 3 | I just might have a problem that you'll understand. We all need somebody to lean on. |
| 4 | ABCDEFGHIJ |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/2nmEfED4)

Answer (score 0):

Separate the replacement values into individual terms and then use `REPLACE` for each value (replacing `%10` before `%1`):

```sql
WITH bounds (id, v, b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6, b7, b8, b9) AS (
  SELECT id,
         vals,
         INSTR(vals, '/', 1, 1),
         INSTR(vals, '/', 1, 2),
         INSTR(vals, '/', 1, 3),
         INSTR(vals, '/', 1, 4),
         INSTR(vals, '/', 1, 5),
         INSTR(vals, '/', 1, 6),
         INSTR(vals, '/', 1, 7),
         INSTR(vals, '/', 1, 8),
         INSTR(vals, '/', 1, 9)
  FROM   table2
),
terms (id, t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6, t7, t8, t9, t10) AS (
  SELECT id,
         CASE
         WHEN b1 = 0 THEN v
         ELSE SUBSTR(v, 1, b1 - 1)
         END,
         CASE
         WHEN b2 = 0 AND b1 > 0 THEN SUBSTR(v, b1 + 1)
         WHEN b2 > 0 AND b1 > 0 THEN SUBSTR(v, b1 + 1, b2 - b1 - 1)
         END,
         CASE
         WHEN b3 = 0 AND b2 > 0 THEN SUBSTR(v, b2 + 1)
         WHEN b3 > 0 AND b2 > 0 THEN SUBSTR(v, b2 + 1, b3 - b2 - 1)
         END,
         CASE
         WHEN b4 = 0 AND b3 > 0 THEN SUBSTR(v, b3 + 1)
         WHEN b4 > 0 AND b3 > 0 THEN SUBSTR(v, b3 + 1, b4 - b3 - 1)
         END,
         CASE
         WHEN b5 = 0 AND b4 > 0 THEN SUBSTR(v, b4 + 1)
         WHEN b5 > 0 AND b4 > 0 THEN SUBSTR(v, b4 + 1, b5 - b4 - 1)
         END,
         CASE
         WHEN b6 = 0 AND b5 > 0 THEN SUBSTR(v, b5 + 1)
         WHEN b6 > 0 AND b5 > 0 THEN SUBSTR(v, b5 + 1, b6 - b5 - 1)
         END,
         CASE
         WHEN b7 = 0 AND b6 > 0 THEN SUBSTR(v, b6 + 1)
         WHEN b7 > 0 AND b6 > 0 THEN SUBSTR(v, b6 + 1, b7 - b6 - 1)
         END,
         CASE
         WHEN b8 = 0 AND b7 > 0 THEN SUBSTR(v, b7 + 1)
         WHEN b8 > 0 AND b7 > 0 THEN SUBSTR(v, b7 + 1, b8 - b7 - 1)
         END,
         CASE
         WHEN b9 = 0 AND b8 > 0 THEN SUBSTR(v, b8 + 1)
         WHEN b9 > 0 AND b8 > 0 THEN SUBSTR(v, b8 + 1, b9 - b8 - 1)
         END,
         CASE
         WHEN b9 > 0 THEN SUBSTR(v, b9 + 1)
         END
  FROM   bounds
)
SELECT t1.id,
       REPLACE(
         REPLACE(
           REPLACE(
             REPLACE(
               REPLACE(
                 REPLACE(
                   REPLACE(
                     REPLACE(
                       REPLACE(
                         REPLACE(text, '%10', t10),
                         '%9', t9
                       ),
                       '%8', t8
                     ),
                     '%7', t7
                   ),
                   '%6', t6
                 ),
                 '%5', t5
               ),
               '%4', t4
             ),
             '%3', t3
           ),
           '%2', t2
         ),
         '%1', t1
       ) AS replaced
FROM   table1 t1
       INNER JOIN terms t
       ON t1.id = t.id
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table1 (ID, TEXT) AS
SELECT 1, 'It is %1 today with a %2 sky.' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'It is %1 today with %2 and chances of %3.' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'I just %1 have a %2 that %3 understand. We %4 need %5 to %6 on.' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE Table2 (ID, VALS) AS
SELECT 1, 'sunny/bright blue' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'rainy/severe thunder storms/flooding' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'might/problem/you''ll/all/somebody/lean' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 1, 'rainy/gloomy' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| ID | REPLACED |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | It is sunny today with a bright blue sky. |
| 2 | It is rainy today with severe thunder storms and chances of flooding. |
| 3 | I just might have a problem that you'll understand. We all need somebody to lean on. |
| 1 | It is rainy today with a gloomy sky. |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/pL4PiADX)

Answer (score 0):

To be independent of the number of variables:

```
with data(id, text) as (
    select 1, 'It is %1 today with a %2 sky.' from dual union all
    select 2, 'It is %1 today with %2 and chances of %3.' from dual union all
    select 3, 'I just %1 have a %2 that %3 understand. We %4 need %5 to %6 on.' from dual -- union all
),
variables(code, id, vals) as (
    select 'A1', 1, 'sunny/bright blue' from dual union all
    select 'A2', 2, 'rainy/severe thunder storms/flooding' from dual union all
    select 'A3', 3, 'might/problem/you''ll/all/somebody/lean' from dual union all
    select 'A4', 1, 'rainy/dark' from dual -- union all
),
compvars(code, id, vid, vals, str, result, isleaf) as (
    select code, v.id, 1 as vid, vals, regexp_substr(vals, '[^/]+', 1, 1) as str,
        replace(d.text, '%1', regexp_substr(vals, '[^/]+', 1, 1)),
        case when 0 < regexp_count(vals, '/') then 0 else 1 end
    from variables v
    join data d on d.id = v.id
    
    union all
    
    select cv.code, cv.id, cv.vid+1, vals, regexp_substr(cv.vals, '[^/]+', 1, cv.vid+1),
        replace(cv.result, '%' || to_char(cv.vid+1), regexp_substr(vals, '[^/]+', 1, cv.vid+1)),
        case when cv.vid < regexp_count(cv.vals, '/') then 0 else 1 end 
    from compvars cv
    where regexp_substr(cv.vals, '[^/]+', 1, cv.vid+1) is not null
)
select code, result from compvars 
where isleaf = 1
;
```

Comment: This fails when there are more than 9 variables [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/kQqLhoep)

Comment: Indeed, then you have to loop in decreasing order.

Answer (score 0):

For more than 10 variables you have to process in reverse order:

```
with data(id, text) as (
    select 1, 'It is %1 today with a %2 sky.' from dual union all
    select 2, 'It is %1 today with %2 and chances of %3.' from dual union all
    select 3, 'I just %1 have a %2 that %3 understand. We %4 need %5 to %6 on.' from dual union all
    select 4, '%1,%2,%3,%4,%5,%6,%7,%8,%9,%10' FROM DUAL
),
variables(code, id, vals) as (
    select 'A1', 1, 'sunny/bright blue' from dual union all
    select 'A2', 2, 'rainy/severe thunder storms/flooding' from dual union all
    select 'A3', 3, 'might/problem/you''ll/all/somebody/lean' from dual union all
    select 'A4', 1, 'rainy/dark' from dual union all
    select 'A5', 4, 'A/B/C/D/E/F/G/H/I/J' FROM dual
),
compvars(code, id, vid, vals, result, isleaf) as (
    select code, v.id, regexp_count(vals, '/') as vid, 
         vals, 
        replace(d.text, '%' || to_char(regexp_count(vals, '/')+1), regexp_substr(vals, '[^/]+', 1, regexp_count(vals, '/')+1)),
        case when 0 < regexp_count(vals, '/') then 0 else 1 end
    from variables v
    join data d on d.id = v.id
    
    union all
    
    select cv.code, cv.id, cv.vid-1, 
        vals, 
        case when cv.vid > 0 then 
            replace(cv.result, '%' || to_char(cv.vid), regexp_substr(vals, '[^/]+', 1, cv.vid)) 
        else null end,
        case when cv.vid = 1 then 1 else 0 end 
    from compvars cv
    where cv.vid <> 0
)
select code, result from compvars 
where isleaf = 1
;
```

Comment: Could you please explain the regexp logic here? Also, is it better to use regexp or instr/substr from a performance stand point when the table2 has million+ rows?

Comment: that could be an optimisation, you would need to pass an additional parameter to keep track of the position in the string where to start the search and then take the substring from that position up to the position of the next "/" -1, the annoying part is that SUBSTR doesn't work with (start position, end position) parameters but with (start position, length) which makes the expression more annoying to write. 
The regexp just collects the characters NOT / from position 1 and returns the "cv.vid" nth occurrence. So yes: version with regexp is for the lazy one and may be less efficient.

Comment: see new version

Answer (score 0):

The version looping in reverse order to support > 9 variables and without regexp functions for better efficiency on large data set:

```
with data(id, text) as (
    select 1, 'It is %1 today with a %2 sky.' from dual union all
    select 2, 'It is %1 today with %2 and chances of %3.' from dual union all
    select 3, 'I just %1 have a %2 that %3 understand. We %4 need %5 to %6 on.' from dual union all
    select 4, '%1,%2,%3,%4,%5,%6,%7,%8,%9,%10' FROM DUAL
),
variables(code, id, vals) as (
    select 'A1', 1, 'sunny/bright blue' from dual union all
    select 'A2', 2, 'rainy/severe thunder storms/flooding' from dual union all
    select 'A3', 3, 'might/problem/you''ll/all/somebody/lean' from dual union all
    select 'A4', 1, 'rainy/dark' from dual union all
    select 'A5', 4, 'A/B/C/D/E/F/G/H/I/J' FROM dual
),
compvars(code, id, vid, vals, result, pos, isleaf) as (
    select code, v.id, length(vals) - length(replace(vals,'/','')) as vid, 
        vals, 
        replace(d.text, '%' || to_char(length(vals) - length(replace(vals,'/',''))+1), 
            substr(vals, instr(vals,'/', -1) + 1)
            ) as s,
        length(vals) - instr(vals,'/', -1) + 1 as pos,
        case when 0 < (length(vals) - length(replace(vals,'/',''))) then 0 else 1 end as c 
    from variables v
    join data d on d.id = v.id
    
    union all
    
    select cv.code, cv.id, cv.vid-1, 
        vals, 
        case when cv.vid > 0 then 
            replace(cv.result, '%' || to_char(cv.vid), 
                substr(vals, instr(vals,'/', -pos-1) + 1, 
                length(vals) - instr(vals,'/', -pos-1) - pos)
            ) 
        else null end,
        length(vals) - instr(vals,'/', -pos-1) + 1 as pos,
        case when cv.vid = 1 then 1 else 0 end 
    from compvars cv
    where cv.vid <> 0
)
select code, result from compvars 
where isleaf = 1
;
```